# Universal property of tensor product and extension of scalars

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

In Dummit and Foote, sec 10.4, Theorem 8, pg number 362. The author gave universal property of extension of scalar.
Let $R$ be a sub ring of a ring $S$. $N$ be a $R$-module and $L$ be a $S-$module (and hence $R$ module) and given any $R$ module homomorphism from $N$ to $L$, we have an $S-$ module homomorphism from $S\otimes N$ to $L$ such that the diagram commutes.

I want to know if it is possible(easily follows) to prove this using universal property of general tensor product. I was trying to prove it for quite sometime. But it couldn't do it. And I feel it may not follows without using additional argument (then just an application of UMP of general tensor product). Please help

Added: you can assume both rings are commutative.

Comment: I don't know how to use tikz-cd in MSE. I tried something ; also I look up at meta but couldn't find it yet. I will add the diagram as soon as I figure out how to use tickz-cd in MSE

Comment: If $f:N \to L$ is an $R$-homomorphism, then check that the map $(s,n)\mapsto sf(n)$ is $R$-bilinear (I believe Dummit and Foote call it “$R$-balanced”). Then invoke the universal property of the tensor product.

Comment: @Alex Sanger, then you will only show the map from tensor product to $L$ is $R-$ module morphism. I want to know if we can show that map is $S-$ module morphism  straightly

Comment: You are right—but once you get the $R$-linear map it’s easy to check using the definition of the $S$-multiplication that it is also $S$-linear.

Comment: Well I think it's just 1 line verification.  Thanks

Comment: Yep, I think that’s all you were missing. Cheers!